# FP precision error on converting XML -> Table & processing it

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml, rounding-error, precision

In SQL Server 2008, I have the value "0.01" in an XML attribute. Using OPENXML, I shred the XML into a temp table. If the applicable column is of type real (single precision), it comes out as 0.01 in the table. Good. However, if the precision is float (double precision), it comes out as 0.00999999977648258. This makes no sense. Why is it doing this?

My next question is that regardless of how the value is represented in the temp table, when I run an aggregate function on it, it always comes back as 0.00999999977648258. This is causing validation errors: the procedure is reporting the input is too small (< 0.01), which is not true.

Any ideas why these rounding errors are happening and how to overcome them?

Already tried: make the column a varchar.

**EDIT2:**

Based on answers, I understand the problem is due to the fact that IEEE numbers cannot represent 0.01 exactly. Therefor my next question:

> "WHERE {computed} < 0.01", why is that
>   0.01 not also being rounded here? If it were, the equation would eval as
>   expected (i.e. 0.00999999977648258 is
>   not < 0.00999999977648258)

**EDIT: Sample code shown**

This code will produce the error. Change the indicated float to real & the error "disappears". At least so far as the temp table goes.

```
DECLARE @XMLText varchar(max)

SET @XMLText = 
'<query prodType="1">
  <param type="1" lowMin="10" hiMax="300">
    <item low="18" hi="20" mode="1" weight="1" />
    <item low="220" hi="220" mode="0" weight="1" />
  </param>
  <param type="2" lowMin="4" hiMax="6">
    <item low="5" hi="5" mode="1" weight="1" />
    <item low="6" hi="6" mode="0" weight="0.01" />
  </param>
  <param type="3" lowMin="0" hiMax="300">
    <item low="34" hi="34" mode="1" weight="0.75" />
    <item low="40" hi="60" mode="1" weight="0.25" />
  </param>
</query>'

DECLARE @hxml int, @sp INT, @StartXCount int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hxml OUTPUT, @XMLText

IF @sp != 0 BEGIN
    SET @Result = '0'
    RETURN
END

DECLARE @t table (
    LowMin         real,
    HiMax          real,
    ParamTypeID    int,
    ParamWeight    float, -- real <<<
    Low            real,
    Hi             real,
    Mode           tinyint          
)

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT      *
FROM        OPENXML (@hxml, '/query/param/item', 2)
WITH        (
                LowMin       real     '../@lowMin',
                HiMax        real     '../@hiMax',
                ParamTypeID  int      '../@type',
                ParamWeight  real     '@weight',
                Low          real     '@low',
                Hi           real     '@hi',
                Mode         tinyint  '@mode'
            )

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.01` can't be stored exactly in an `IEEE` type, since it's not representable with a fraction with a power of `2` in denominator.

However, what I can reproduce is the opposite of what you are saying:

```
SELECT  CAST(0.01 AS FLOAT) AS value
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE

<value>1.000000000000000e-002</value>
```

```
SELECT  CAST(0.01 AS REAL) AS value
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE

<value>9.9999998e-003</value>
```

Could you please post your exact query?

**Update:**

I get the same results with your code: `0,01` when `ParamWeight` is `FLOAT`, `0,00999999977648258` when it's `REAL`.

**Update 2:**

`IEEE` types are stored as a sign, mantissa and a significand. For a `32`-bit value, mantissa is the binary logarithm of the greatest power of 2 (least than the value), and a significand is a `23`-bit binary fraction (a number from `1` to `2`, the leading `1` is not stored.).

In your case it's `-7` for the mantissa `(2^-7 = 1/128 = 0,0078125)`, and `1.01000111101011100001010` for the significand `(= 1 + 2348810 / 8388608 = 1,2799999713897705078125)`.

The resulting number is a product of these numbers which is close to `0.01` but still not close enough to avoid errors in `15`'th digit (which precision `SQL Server` considers important)

Comment: Thanks @Quassnoi :) I posted the sample code. However, you gave the reason... IEEE. Ps. did you receive my email?

Comment: @IanC: even with your code, `REAL` yields less precise result than `FLOAT`. Yes, I did, will look it the next Monday.

Comment: @Quassnoi then is must be as @Alex stated: the ToString function. It's showing 0.01 which "looks" more accurate, but isn't. But when I say "WHERE {computed} < 0.01", why is that 0.01 not also being rounded? If it were, the equation would eval as expected (i.e. 0.00999999977648258 is not < 0.00999999977648258).

Comment: @Quassnoi, make it "real" in the OPENXML statement and "float" in the table def => 0.00999...; make it "real" or "float" in both => 0.01. Weird.

Comment: I solved it by making both the table and the OPENXML field types float. Then all numbers are float, including the 0.01 literal in the WHERE statement, which means they all suffer identical rounding errors, thus eliminating the problem.

Comment: Alternately, saying "WHERE {computed} < CAST(0.01 AS real)" works too. I should have known this!

Comment: @IanC: this depends on what exactly your condition looks like and what are the types of the underlying columns. For instance, `0.01` and `0.1E-1` are different types (`DECIMAL(3, 2)` and `FLOAT`). `CAST(0.01 AS REAL) = 0.01` is `TRUE`, since `REAL` is cast into less precise `DECIMAL(3, 2)`, but `CAST(0.01 AS REAL) = 0.1E-1` is `FALSE`, since `REAL` is cast into more precise `FLOAT` and precision differences begin to matter.

Comment: @Quassnoi True. The lesson I learned today is to stick with the same typed throughout. This includes understanding what SQL Server is doing: an aggregate function returns a float type; a numeric literal in SQL is treated as float, whereas a numeric literal in an if statement is dynamically typed to fit the context. By having the same type throughout, the errors are, all things given, "equal", and thus cancel out.

Comment: When you say "REAL is cast into more precise FLOAT" - I take it you mean "literal is cast into more precise FLOAT". It isn't typed yet.

Comment: @IanC: the `REAL` on the left side of the equation is cast to a `FLOAT` on the right side of the equation. Every constant is typed, and a constant in scientific notation is typed as `FLOAT`.

Comment: @Quassnoi I don't believe it works like that. The "0.01" literal is dynamically typed. If we make the first CAST AS either real or float, they both return true as the 0.01 is being dynamically typed by the compiler/interpreter as real or float. In the second example, the compiler/interpreter is seeing scientific notation, and forcing a type of float, resulting in the equation being true only for a CAST AS of float. The logic of this holds up and is unquestionably true for languages like Delphi / C# / C. Of course, under the hood in SQL Server, it may be doing what you say, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because the computer **CANNOT** represent the value 0.01 in floating point both in single and double precision. This value is rounded to the nearest representable value both in float and in double. So in both cases it's not 0.01, but only displayed to you as 0.01 in the real case (I don't know how does the ToString algorithm for floating point work, so can't tell you why it is converted to 0.01 in one case and 0.00999999977648258 in another).

The only thing I can tell you for sure - in the real case it was rounded to a representable value ABOVE 0.01 and in the double case it was rounded to a representable value BELOW 0.01. Therefore validation failed in the double precision case.

To overcome this problem you can change your validation test to be "smaller than 0.01 - epsilon" for some very small epsilon.

Comment: I believe that I'd have to include the epsilon, as you state.

Comment: Surely if 0.01 is rounded, and we ran a sum against a column that came to approx. 0.01, then compared it to "0.01" (which would itself be rounded), then the result should work as expected? However, the "0.01" input appears to NOT be round, but is being evaluated as a true 0.01. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a true 0.01" because 0.01 cannot be represented in floating point. It IS rounded, both in single and double precision. It's displayed to you as 0.01 by a "float --> string" conversion algorithm (what you see as 0.01 is a string containing a decimal *approximation* to the true binary floating point value stored).